# Teamcity not working with warn messages in logs

Tags: linux, teamcity

I've installed Teamcity v9 on my VPS and I have some trouble with it:
it's not working at all.

My OS is Debian x64, oracle jdk8 is installed and env variables are ok.
Here are parts of log files:

Also I've disabled firewall to make sure this doesn't affect Teamcity.
My Teamcity configs are default(I've changed nothing there).

Thanks for your time and help.

Also I've noticed warn message from Amazon EC2 plugin, but my VPS is no way belongs to Amazon.

```
[2016-03-24 21:19:05,111]   INFO - s.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2 - =========================================================== 
[2016-03-24 21:19:05,248]   INFO - s.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2 - TeamCity Build Agent 9.1.6 (build 37459), OS: Linux, User: andrey, JRE: 1.8.0_77, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03, mixed mode), Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.8.0_77-b03), Oracle Corporation, JVM parameters: -ea -Xmx384m -Dteamcity_logs=../logs/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/teamcity-agent-log4j.xml 
[2016-03-24 21:19:05,248]   INFO - s.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2 - Starting... 
[2016-03-24 21:19:05,705]   INFO - buildServer.agent.AgentMain2$2 - Refreshing jetbrains.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2$2@3b0143d3: startup date [Thu Mar 24 21:19:05 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy 
[2016-03-24 21:19:11,104]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Calculating CPU benchmark index... 
[2016-03-24 21:19:24,495]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - CPU benchmark index is set to 461 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,010]   INFO - dAgentConfigurationInitializer - Loading build agent configuration from ../conf/buildAgent.properties 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,288]   INFO - s.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2 - Working dir: /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,288]   INFO - s.buildServer.agent.AgentMain2 - Temp dir: /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,292]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - =========================================================== 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,293]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - Plugins initialization started... 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,300]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - Scanning plugins folders 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,301]   INFO - .plugins.files.JarSearcherBase - Scanning plugin folder: /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,304]   INFO - .plugins.files.JarSearcherBase - Scanning plugin folder: /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/tools 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,331]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - Found 1 plugins: [amazonEC2] 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,332]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginsCollection - Load shared classloader for 1 plugins [amazonEC2] 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,343]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginsCollection - No plugins were loaded with standalone classloaders 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,606]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - Plugins initialization completed: 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,607]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - Loaded 1 plugins: [amazonEC2] 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,608]   INFO - rver.plugins.PluginManagerImpl - =========================================================== 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,618]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Build Agent version: 37459, plugins signature: NA 
[2016-03-24 21:19:25,619]   INFO - dAgentConfigurationInitializer - Loading build agent configuration from ../conf/buildAgent.properties 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,705]   INFO - n.AmazonInstanceMetadataReader - Amazon is not available. Amazon EC2 integration is not active: Failed to connect to http://169.254.169.254/latest. The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 7000 ms 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,705]   INFO - .agent.AmazonPropertiesUpdater - Fetched AmazonEC2 instance metadata:  
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,710]   INFO - zon.agent.AmazonMetadataChecks - Amazon EC instance metadata contains no keys 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,711]   WARN - .agent.AmazonPropertiesUpdater - Fetched Amazon EC2 instance metadata does not contain required values. Probably this agent was not started inside Amazon EC2. Is proxy server used? 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,755]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Start build agent 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,769]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Agent Web server started on port 9090 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,787]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Writing agent runtime file to /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/logs/buildAgent.xmlRpcPort 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,788]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Launcher version is 37459 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,789]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Writing agent runtime file to /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/logs/buildAgent.xmlRpcPort :DONE! 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,789]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Build agent started 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,791]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentDetailsFactory - Build agent ownAddress will be defined by the server. Define 'ownAddress' property in the conf/buildAgent.properties file 
[2016-03-24 21:19:32,811]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server http://localhost:8111, AgentDetails{Name='Default Agent', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=    [185.117.153.58, 172.17.0.1], Port=9090, Version='37459', PluginsVersion='NA', AvailableRunners=[], AvailableVcs=[], AuthorizationToken='', PingCode='mszNIWqOgYRCSEayT8GFeteuxOzRU50X'} 
[2016-03-24 21:19:33,282]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Cleaning up items with life time in cache greater than 172800 seconds 
[2016-03-24 21:19:33,284]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Finished cleaning up expired items, 0 items removed 
[2016-03-24 21:19:33,285]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/.old 
[2016-03-24 21:19:33,543]   INFO - l.directories.DirectoryMapImpl - Cleaning up old checkout directories. Default lifetime = 192 hour(s) 
[2016-03-24 21:19:33,681]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/.old 
[2016-03-24 21:24:33,891]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Failed to resolve server communication protocol. Will try all protocols: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out (enable debug to see stacktrace) 
[2016-03-24 21:24:33,892]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Trying to register using 'polling' protocol. 
[2016-03-24 21:24:34,175]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Cleaning up items with life time in cache greater than 172800 seconds 
[2016-03-24 21:24:34,175]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Finished cleaning up expired items, 0 items removed 
[2016-03-24 21:24:34,176]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/.old 
[2016-03-24 21:24:34,269]   INFO - l.directories.DirectoryMapImpl - Cleaning up old checkout directories. Default lifetime = 192 hour(s) 
[2016-03-24 21:24:34,294]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/.old 
[2016-03-24 21:29:33,923]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registration using 'polling' failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out (enable debug to see stacktrace) 
[2016-03-24 21:29:33,926]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Trying to register using 'xml-rpc' protocol. 
[2016-03-24 21:29:34,176]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Cleaning up items with life time in cache greater than 172800 seconds 
[2016-03-24 21:29:34,177]   INFO - r.artifacts.impl.HttpDiskCache - Finished cleaning up expired items, 0 items removed 
[2016-03-24 21:29:34,178]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/.old 
[2016-03-24 21:29:34,331]   INFO - l.directories.DirectoryMapImpl - Cleaning up old checkout directories. Default lifetime = 192 hour(s) 
[2016-03-24 21:29:34,396]   INFO - dDirectoryBasedCleanupRegistry - Removing files from /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/.old
```

Comment: How are you checking whether it's working or not? According to logs everything works.

Comment: Well, I was trying to access it by address:port from my Dev pc's browser